# Selecting 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select an attribute from another table with the original table

Comment: Would be simpler and more flexible if you changed the database design for `user_group` to be only `user, type` then store 1 or 2 or 3 or even 99 rows to indicate a user is in a group

Comment: Sample data with expected output will help to understand this better

Comment: And are you using MySQL or Postgress? Spamming tags does not really help

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy added a sample

Comment: After you removed all the explanation, your question doesn't make sense any more.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data model.  You should have three tables:

- `users`: one row per users
- `groups`: one row per groups
- `user_groups`: one row per user/group combination

With your data model, I would use arrays to unpivot the values and then reaggregate:

I prefer arrays to JSON, so I would use:

```
select ug.type,
       (select array_agg(u.name)
        from (unnest(array[ug.user_1, ug.user_2, ug.user_3])) ar(user_id) join
             users u
             on u.user_id = u.id
       ) as users
from user_groups ug;
```

You can use a JSON function if you really want JSON.