# Selecting two tables at the same time

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have **users** and **user_groups** tables like following:

**users**

```
id - PK
name
timestamp
```

**user_groups**

```
user_1 - Foreign key to users id
user_2 - Foreign key to users id
user_3 - Foreign key to users id
type
```

I have a user having id = 1. I want to select all the groups that this user joint, **the name of the group members** and the **type of the user group**. Can I do that with only one query? What would be the best way to achieve this?

**Sample Data**

*users*

```
id - 1
name - Jeff

id - 2
name - Mehmet

id - 3
name - Walter
```

*user_ groups*

```
user_1 - 1
user_2 - 2
user_3 - null
type - 1

user_1 - 1
user_2 - 2
user_3 - 3
type - 1

user_1 - 1
user_2 - 3
user_3 - null
type - 2
```

How output should be:

```
[{
type: 1,
name: ["Jeff", "Mehmet"]
},

{
type: 1,
name: ["Jeff","Mehmet","Walter"]
},

{
type: 2,
name: ["Jeff", "Mehmet"]
}]
```

Comment: Yes, that's the whole idea of joins: you're joining two tables together in one query. In this case you want to select type and name from user_groups table joining user_group name to the user's table name column.

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want multiple joins and some array functionality:

```
select ug.type,
       array_remove(array[u1.name, u2.name, u3.name], null)
from user_groups ug left join
     users u1
     on ug.user_1 = u1.id left join
     users u2
     on ug.user_2 = u2.id left join
     users u3
     on ug.user_3 = u3.id;
```